# Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”?

Tags: c, xcode, string, pointers, fgets

I'm making this little program that just reads contents of a file, but when I run it I get this error: Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

I also get a warning from Xcode: "Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast" at line 10 of my code (main.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FILE_LOCATION "../../Data"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    FILE *dataFile;
    char c;

    if ( dataFile = fopen(FILE_LOCATION, "r") == NULL ) {
        printf("FAILURE!");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ( (c = fgetc(dataFile)) != EOF ) {
        printf("%c", c);
    }

    fclose(dataFile);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the debugger output:

```
[Session started at 2012-06-27 10:28:13 +0200.]
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1515) (Sat Jan 15 08:33:48 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys000
Loading program into debugger…
Program loaded.
run
[Switching to process 34331]
Running…
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
(gdb)
```

Is there a problem with the pointer, wrong function? I found something to track memory issues wich is called NSZombie, what is that and can I use it?

Comment: `if ( (dataFile = fopen(FILE_LOCATION, "r")) == NULL ) {`

Comment: @wildplasser: that should be an answer not comment.

Comment: At your service. (but I think it is too trivial for a Q/A)

Comment: Since you mention NSZombie: NSZombie is an Objective-C class used to track down errors in the memory/lifecycle management of Objective-C objects . It is not relevant here in C code.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( (dataFile = fopen(FILE_LOCATION, "r")) == NULL ) {
```

Comment: +1. Would be nice if you could add that this is about operator precedence. i.e. `==` binds tighter than `=`.

Comment: The strange thing is that he did not make the same error in the fgetc() line. (he made another error instead ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another error:

```
char c;

while ( (c = fgetc(dataFile)) != EOF ) {
```

You should really study the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc) for important functions like `fgetc()` before using them.

Specifically, `fgetc()` returns `int`, which is required in order to fit the `EOF` value. If it returned `char`, then there would have to be one character whose numerical value collided with `EOF` and that, thus, couldn't appear in a binary file. That would suck, so that's not how it works. :)